# Fremdwörter in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten

Tags: word-choice

Ich schreibe gerade an dem Bericht für mein Fachpraktikum und werde demnächst meine Bachelorarbeit beginnen. Zur Info: ich studiere einen Ingenieursstudiengang an einer technischen Universität.

Nun meine Frage an euch:

In welchem Rahmen ist es üblich / zulässig in solchen Texten Begriffe (Redewendungen) wie "vice versa", "dito", "de facto" und so weiter zu verwenden oder sollte ich es vermeiden bzw. auf ein Minimum reduzieren?

Comment: In welcher Situation würdest Du *dito* überhaupt in geschriebener Sprache verwenden (abgesehen von Instant-Messengern u. Ä.), geschweige denn in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit?

Comment: Berechtigte frage, hatte es glaube ich in englischer Fachliteratur gelesen. Dort ist es auch deutlich häufiger, dass lateinische Phrasen verwendet werden. Die drei Beispiele waren nur das, was mir auf de schnelle eingefallen ist und sollte keines Wegs vollständig sein.

Comment: Aus meiner (österr.) Sichtweise spricht überhaupt nichts gegen "dito" oder "detto". Es ist ein normales, stadardsprachliches Wort, dessen Verwendung freilich keineswegs zwingend ist.

Comment: Ich zitiere hierzu einmal: "Der immense Usus exterritorialer Vokabeln in der germanistischen Linguistik ist mit dezidiertem Fanatismus auf das maximale Minimum zu reduzieren!" -> Gebrauche so wenige Fremdwörter wie möglich.

Comment: @Ingmar: Falls sich das auf meinen Kommentar bezog: Es ging mir nicht um die Angemessenheit von *dito,* sondern darum dass es nun mal nur in Dialogen verwendet wird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grundsätzlich halte ich die Verwendung von Redewendungen für unproblematisch, solange sie der Intention des Textes dienlich sind - etwa im Rahmen eines veranschaulichenden Beispiels oder einer Analogie, die das Verständnis fördern soll. Auf Kosten der inhaltlichen Genauigkeit sollte die Verwendung natürlich nicht gehen.

Im deutschen akademischen Umfeld herrscht leider eine Tradition, Sachverhalte in einer möglichst nüchternen und exakten, dafür unanschaulichen Sprache zu formulieren - der Unterschied zum anglosächsischen Sprachraum fällt gerade bei Lehrbüchern im naturwissenschaftlich-technischen Bereich schnell auf.

Insofern würde ich ggf. mit dem Betreuer Rücksprache halten (bzw. einen Blick in dessen Publikationen und ihren Sprachstil werfen). Bei der Bewertung ingenieurtechnischer Arbeiten sollte die Ausformulierung jenseits des mathematischen Formalismus aber in der Regel keine Rolle spielen.

Zu den konkreten Begriffen:

- 'de facto' ist völlig unproblematisch und meinem Sprachgefühl nach auch keineswegs dünkelhaft. Im Zweifel passen meistens auch 'effektiv' und 'faktisch'.
- 'dito' ist definitiv umgangssprachlich.
- 'vice versa' klingt gegenüber 'und umgekehrt' arg gekünstelt, würde ich persönlich also vermeiden.

Comment: Wie schon oben erwähnt, ist dito jdf. im öst. Standardeutsch absolut üblich, keine Rede von ugs. "Ebenso" tuts aber auch.

Answer (score 5):

Hängt von der Redewendung ab. Meine Meinung zu deinen Beispielen:

- "de facto" ist akzeptabel, da nicht mit Umgangssprache assoziiert.
- "dito" ist Umgangssprache, also in der Arbeit zu vermeiden.
- "vice versa" ist in meiner Erfahrung im Deutschen nicht verwendet, oder bestenfalls entweder sehr altmodisch oder sehr neumodisch (denglisch).

Comment: Vice versa ist lateinisch und kommt daher womöglich aus einem akademischen Sprachgebrauch. Dito dagegen kommt aus dem französichen. De facto ist ebenfalls lateinischen Ursprungs und in Kombination mit de jure gängiger Juristenterminus.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin der Meinung, Redewendungen haben in technisch/wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten nichts verloren. Aufpassen muss man auch mit Denglish/Anglizismen (z. B. downloaden, updaten, mailen etc.)

Zu den genannten Redewendungen:

- Die Aussage "de facto" kann leicht überheblich wirken, was in solchen Arbeiten vermieden werden sollte.
- Der Gebrauch des Wortes "dito" ist wie bereits zuvor genannt – und auch laut Duden – nur umgangssprachlich gebraucht und daher zu vermeiden.
- "vice versa" ist laut Duden bildungssprachlich im Einsatz und kann daher meiner Meinung nach ohne weiteres verwendet werden.

Answer (score 2):

Obwohl die anderen Antworten "de facto" für unproblematisch halten, muss ich doch sagen, dass ich es zumindest in meiner Magisterarbeit nicht verwendet hätte. Ich komme auch von einer technischen Universität und mein Professor war sehr an trockener, präziser Sprache interessiert. Das Problem, dass ich mit "de facto" sehe, ist nicht so sehr die Phrase an sich, sondern der Inhalt.

Was ist "de facto" ("faktisch") in einer naturwissenschaftlichen Arbeit. Entweder etwas ist so oder nicht. "de facto" hat für mich eine Art Interpretation in sich … ich bewerte etwas als Fakt und genau das sollte man vermeiden. Natürlich kommt es auf den Zusammenhang an, aber ich kann mir vorstellen, dass es dem einen oder anderen Korrektor aufstößt (wie auch "faktisch")

"Dito" hat meiner Ansicht nach nichts in einer Arbeit zu sagen und bezüglich "und vice versa" habe ich eine [Google Scholar Suche](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&q=%22und%20vice%20versa%22&btnG=&lr=) gemacht. Ergebnis: Es kommt 13.000-mal vor. Sogar in Titeln.

Und zum Vergleich, [hier das Ergebnis](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=%22ist%20de%20facto%22&btnG=&hl=de&as_sdt=0,5) für "ist de facto"

Comment: [Meine Suche nach *de facto*](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=%22de+facto%22&&hl=de&lr=lang_de) liefert ein etwas anderes Ergebnis. Außerdem kann *de facto* nicht einfach mit *faktisch* oder *tatsächlich* gleichgesetzt werden, sondern wird speziell in Situationen verwendet, in denen es einen Kontrast zwischen der De-facto- und der De-jure-Situation gibt. Schließlich ist z. B. [*De-facto-Regime*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-facto-Regime) ein sinnvoller wissenschaftlicher Fachbegriff, wenn mich nicht alles täuscht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... ja, stimmt. Ich habe nach "ist defacto" gesucht um Englische Treffer auszuschließen. Und ich habe von einer rein, nennen wir's mal "messtechnischen" Perspektive argumentiert. Ich wollte die anderen Antworten einfach nicht unwiedersprochen stehen lassen.

Comment: Schreib vielleicht besser *naturwissenschaftlich* statt *wissenschaftlich.* Was Ingenieurswissenschaften angeht, könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass der Begriff *De-facto-Standard* in einer Arbeit fallen könnte, weiß es aber auch nicht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft.. hab's geändert. Danke. Ja, De-Facto-Standard kann ich mir vorstellen. Mir ging es um "de facto" in "normalen" Statements... z.B. "etwas ist "de facto" nicht nachweisbar." Da würde ich es rauslassen, auch wenn man's beim Sprechen verwendet... aber mein Prof war da wirklich extrem.

Answer (score 1):

Was heißt, bitte, in diesem Zusammenhang "zulässig"? Sprache ist ja kein Selbstzweck. Wenn Du das, was Du sagen möchtest, mit einem fachsprachlichen Ausdruck am besten ausdrücken kannst, dann verwende ihn, sonst nicht. In einem wissenschaftlichen Text, der sich in aller Regel an (angehende) Akademiker wendet, kann man natürlich ein anderes Sprachniveau verwenden als in der Tagespresse; zwingend ist das aber nicht. In der (vor allem) deutschen Lehre und Forschung herrscht m. E. die Meinung vor, nur wer sich "kompliziert" ausdrücke, schreibe "wissenschaftlich". Um es mit Karl Popper zu sagen: "Wer's nicht einfach und klar sagen kann, der soll schweigen und weiterarbeiten, bis er's klar sagen kann."

Ich hätte keine Bedenken, die von Dir genannten Begriffe zu verwenden, aber das gilt auch für "umgekehrt", "ebenso" und "faktisch". Aber am besten besprichst Du das mit Deinem Betreuer, denn letztlich muss es für ihn passen.

Comment: Ich war kurz davor den Beitrag aufzuwerten, da schlug der letzte Satz zu. Ein Betreuer hat sich ja wohl eines persönlichen Geschmackurteils zu enthalten. Entweder ein bestimmter Stil ist vorgegeben, und gilt dann unabhängig vom Betreuer, oder nicht. Es kann doch nicht dem Geschmacksempfinden eines Betreuers überlassen sein, wie man zu schreiben hat!

Comment: Willkommen in der Realität. Selbstverständlich wird man sich beim Verfassen einer Arbeit am Zielpublikum orientieren, und im Fall einer studentischen wissenschaftlichen Arbeit ist das in erster Linie nun einmal der Betreuer. Wer das verkennt, kömpft völlig umsonst gegen Windmühlen.

Answer (score 0):

Meine Empfehlung ist, derartige Redewendungen zu vermeiden, da diese typischerweise nicht für das Verstehen beim Leser notwendig sind, und es oft einfachere Wörter gibt, die gleichwertig sind. Je einfacher Du Dich ausdrückst, umso besser wirst Du verstanden.